# AWS CodeBuild not producing any artifacts when build runs `next build` successfully

Tags: npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, next.js, devops, aws-codebuild

I am using NextJS and attempting to do CI to build and deploy onto AWS Beanstalk.

This is my `buildspec.yml`

```yaml
version: 0.2
env:
  variables:
    NODE_ENV: "production"
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Installing dependencies
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Building nextjs app
      - npm run build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

I am monitoring the logs and there are no errors, but there are no artifacts being produced by the **Build** stage. So once the pipeline moves onto the **Deploy** stage. I get this error in the logs:

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/web.stdout.log
----------------------------------------
Nov 30 01:47:31 ip-172-31-50-67 web: at /var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next:26:341
Nov 30 01:47:31 ip-172-31-50-67 web: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Nov 30 01:47:31 ip-172-31-50-67 web: npm ERR! errno 1
Nov 30 01:47:31 ip-172-31-50-67 web: npm ERR! with-typescript@1.0.0 start: `next start`
Nov 30 01:47:31 ip-172-31-50-67 web: npm ERR! Exit status 1
Nov 30 01:47:31 ip-172-31-50-67 web: npm ERR!
Nov 30 01:47:31 ip-172-31-50-67 web: npm ERR! Failed at the with-typescript@1.0.0 start script.
Nov 30 01:47:31 ip-172-31-50-67 web: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
Nov 30 01:47:31 ip-172-31-50-67 web: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Nov 30 01:47:31 ip-172-31-50-67 web: npm ERR!     /home/webapp/.npm/_logs/2020-11-30T01_47_31_607Z-debug.log
Nov 30 01:47:32 ip-172-31-50-67 web: > with-typescript@1.0.0 start /var/app/current
Nov 30 01:47:32 ip-172-31-50-67 web: > next start
Nov 30 01:47:32 ip-172-31-50-67 web: Error: Could not find a valid build in the '/var/app/current/.next' directory! Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the server.
Nov 30 01:47:32 ip-172-31-50-67 web: at Server.readBuildId (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:137:355)
Nov 30 01:47:32 ip-172-31-50-67 web: at new Server (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:3:120)
Nov 30 01:47:32 ip-172-31-50-67 web: at createServer (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:2:638)
Nov 30 01:47:32 ip-172-31-50-67 web: at start (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:1:323)
Nov 30 01:47:32 ip-172-31-50-67 web: at nextStart (/var/app/current/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-start.js:19:125)
```

I don't understand what more I can do? I have tried changing the **Artifacts** settings for the **Build** stage to encrypted and unencrypted, I have tried *No cache*, *Local*, and *Amazon S3* with a Cache Bucket. None of these seem to produce any artifacts.

Can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your pipeline defintion?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I don't know what you mean by definition? I am using the basic AWS CodePipeline setup and nothing errors out. In the Build stage of the pipeline it succeeds to build and everything, but the artifacts are not being exported from the Build stage to the Deploy stage

Comment: I mean, how did you set it up? What are the definitions of your stages in CodePipeline?

Comment: **Build**
Action provider: **AWS CodeBuild**
Input Artifacts: (name of the source artifacts)
Build type: Single Build
Output artifacts: buildartifacts

Comment: What is the `Input Artifact` of deploy action? It should be `buildartifacts`.

Comment: Ah somehow it was not set to that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by incorrect setting of `Input Artifact` in a deploy action which is following the build action. The `Input Artifact` should be set to `buildartifacts` which is an output artifact from the build action.

Answer (score 0):

@Marcin pointed out that I needed to double check the Deploy artifacts name and make sure it is the same as the build artifacts output name